# How to get HTML form data opened in Webkit.Net

Tags: c#, .net, webkit.net

I have a HTML5 page loaded in Webkit.Net. Now, I am trying to get the data enetered by user on HTML page.
I am trying the following code:
WebKit.DOM.Document doc1 = webKitBrowser1.Document;
WebKit.DOM.Element name1 = doc1.GetElementById("email");
string test1 = name1.GetAttribute("value");

The code is not working. Value of email element is not coming in test1.
Am I missing something? Do anyone know any workaround or any other method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much a duplicate of [Get HTML input text value in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189617/get-html-input-text-value-in-webkit)

The solution is

```
String test1 = webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('email').value");
```