# Get HTML input text value in webkit

Tags: c#, winforms, webkit, webkit.net

What is the appropriate syntax for retrieving an HTML form's input text box "value" (ie, what the user has typed into the said field) ?

I've tried the `<webkitControlName>.Document.GetElementById("email").GetAttribute("value").ToString()`
but it always returns blank/empty/null, regardless of what has been typed into the field.

VS2012, .NET 4CP

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
var inputValue = <webkitControl>.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('email').value");
```